# Is there a way to update all columns in a table using R?

Tags: r

I have a List which is sourced from a table in MariaDB. After making changes in the table, I am trying to update all the columns in the table with the columns from the List. 
db.WriteTable() updates only a specific set of columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to overwrite everything then why not empty the table first? And then write your new data?

```
# Library
library(odbc)

# Creating connection
my_connection <- dbConnect(drv = odbc::odbc(),
                           Driver = "SQL Driver",
                           server = 00.00.00.00\\\\mycoolservername,1434,
                           database = "databasename",
                           uid = "user",
                           pwd = "password")

# Removing old data
query = "DELETE FROM my_schema.my_table"
dbGetQuery(my_connection, query)

# Inserting new data
dbWriteTable(my_connection, schema = "my_schema", name = "my_table", value = my_dataframe)
```